# Does there exist an intermediate step of completion of the algebraic closure $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ to get the field $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, complete-spaces

We know that completion of the field of rationals $\mathbb{Q}$ is the field $\mathbb{R}$ of reals with respect to usual metric.

Next, algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}$ is the field $\mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers.

**My question:**

Does there exist an intermediate step of completion of the algebraic closure $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ to get the field $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Because,

I understand the matter. But actually in p-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is the completion of the rational $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to the p-adic absolute value and algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_p$. Then completion of  $\bar{$\mathbb{Q}}_p$  with respect to p-adic absolute value is the field $\Omega$ which is analogous to $\mathbb{C}$.

So can I say that trivially, algebraic closure of $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ is $\mathbb{C}$ ?

Comment: As $\Bbb C=\Bbb R[i]$ is a quadratic extension, there is little room for intermediate steps

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen, But,  The completion of the algebraic closure of a valued field $K$ is algebraically closed and complete.

So any further operation of closure or completion gives you a field isomorphic to $\hat{\bar{K}}$.

Comment: The first completion refers to "Cachy completion" apparently?

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Hagen von Eitzen's point is that for any field $F$ such that $\bar{\mathbb R}\subseteq F\subseteq\mathbb C$,  $[\mathbb C:F]$ must divide $[\mathbb C:\mathbb R]=2$,

Comment: I do not understand the question *Does there exist an intermediate step of completion of the algebraic closure $\bar{ℝ}$ to get the field ℂ?*. The algebraic closure of $\mathbb R$ is $\mathbb C$. What meaningful step would be between the two?  Or I could be confused by what you want to mean by $\bar{}$ and $\hat{}$ (because you haven't explained...)

Comment: @rschwieb, so if I assume that algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ and completion of $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$  is the field $\mathbb{C}$.  Can  I say that?

Comment: This is mostly repeating what others have said, but since $[\mathbb{C}:\mathbb{R}]=2$ and nontrivial field extensions have positive degree (and degree is multiplicative), if you believe that $\mathbb{R}$ is not algebraically closed but $\mathbb{C}$ is, and if you believe that $\mathbb{C}$ is complete (with respect to the unique absolute value -- up to equivalence -- on $\mathbb{C}$ which restricts to the absolute value you used on $\mathbb{Q}$), then you don't have room to wonder whether something is happening between $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and its completion, which must be $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @M.A.SARKAR Are you asking if $\mathbb C$ is Cauchy complete?

Comment: @csprun, I understand the matter. But actually in p-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is the completion of the rational $\mathbb{Q}$ with respect to the p-adic absolute value and algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is $\bar{$\mathbb{Q}}_p$. Then completion of  $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}_p$  with respect to p-adic absolute value is the field $\Omega$ which is analogous to $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @rschwieb, yes Cauchy Complete with respect to usual absolute value or metric. Please see my above comment and edited question.

Comment: A finite-dimensional normed real vector space (whose topology in the 2-d case necessarily agrees with the usual absolute value induced topology on $\mathbb{C}$) is always Cauchy complete, as are finite-dimensional normed vector spaces over any complete valued field. See [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/equivnorms.pdf).